# EF Core fill missing data

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core, upgrade, entity-framework-core-migrations

My problem is simple, I just wonder about best practices. Let's say we have two objects, A and B, where B is a property of B, as so:

```
public class A {
    public B b {get; set;}
}
```

This is V1 of the code, A is mapped via EF to a SQL database.

Now V2 comes along, where A gets another class property, C.

```
public class A {
    public B b {get; set;}
    public C c {get; set;}
}
```

Since a bunch of A instances have been created and stored in V1, the migration leaves them with a null value for property c. All newly created instances of A of course have barebones instances of B and C created on initialization.

Now the V2 client expects a retrieved instance of A to have both b and c (neither null).

How would I go about filling in the missing objects? At migration, a one-time script, checking each object for nulls on retrieval (tricky if you miss an include statement), some other technique?

How is this usually handled?

Best regards,
JasonX

Comment: At migration, using `migrationBuilder.Sql(...);`

Comment: Do you already have all the data to make object `C` for each record?

Comment: The data is actually empty, I just need an empty instance with an assigned Id, as it is part of the failsafe demands. Basically, all I need is c =new C { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };